# El controlador no me elimina el registro

Tags: laravel

Buen día,

creé un método para eliminar cierto registro de una tabla, y todo se ejecuta correctamente y no me aparece ningún mensaje de error, pero no me elimina el registro; si alguien me pudiera por favor ayudar o recomendar algún tipo de solución

/*  Controlador */

```
public function nofav($id){

    Reacciones::findOrFail($id)->delete();

    return response()->json([
        'success' => 'Record deleted successfully!'
    ]);
}
```

/*  rutas */

```
route::delete('discover/{id}','DiscoverNewsController@nofav');
```

/* Ajax */ lo uso para pasarle el id,  al controlador ya que no uso formulario (igual lo intente pero tampoco funciona)

```
$(".favs-").click(function(data){
 
    var route="discover"
    var idfav = this.id;
 
    var route="discover/"+idfav;
 
    $.ajax({
       headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
       data:{
           Id:idfav,
        },
       url: route,
       type: "DELETE",
       success:function(data){
            console.log("Ok!");
       }
    });
 
});
```

Comment: el id esta llegando al controlador correctamente si haces un
dump($id) ??

Comment: Revisa que se envíe la solicitud desde la pestaña network del navegador, ahi veras si te arroja algún error.

Answer (score 0):

Para probar posibles soluciones empezá con ver si recibís bien el id:

`dd($id);`

Si recibís bien buscá el registro antes de intentar borrarlo y hace otro dd para ver si lo encuentra correctamente:

```
$reaccion=Reacciones::find($id);
dd($reaccion);
```

Si esto pasa bien ya el borrado debería funcionar:

```
$reaccion->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Logré solucionarlo, y quisiera compartirlo por si alguien llega a tener el mismo inconveniente.

Laravel por defecto trabaja con el nombre "id" , y si el programador crea su propio id con otro nombre, como me ocurrió, este debe ser declarado o cambiarlo como se maneja por defecto (id) y es sensible a mayusculas, ya que, yo lo tenia con Id y por eso no me eliminaba.